# Flow - typesafe actions

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, flowtype, type-safety

I'm using flow and I want to make my reducers more type safe. I came across this comment that suggests a solution that I find kind of nice and fitting inside my codebase:
https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/issues/992#issuecomment-191152574

I'm trying to port it to flow using the `%checks` keyword but it's not working.

My code:

```js
export type Action<T> = {
  type: string,
  payload: T,
};

interface ActionCreator<P> {
  type: string;
  (payload: P): Action<P>;
}

export function actionCreator<P>(type: string): ActionCreator<P> {
  return Object.assign((payload: P) => ({ type, payload }), { type });
}

export function isActionOfType<P>(
  action: Action<any>,
  creator: ActionCreator<P>
): boolean %checks {
  return action.type === creator.type;
}
```

Whenever I use it in the reducer function like this

```js
(...)
case isActionOfType(action, getArticles):
  // action.payload is still any
(...)
```

Am I doing something wrong? Is it possible to get this typescript solution working in flow? Or should I use a different approach? If yes then what are your suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, you would not use a `case` statement, but an `if` statement.

There is no rule you have to use a case statement in Redux, in fact we do not really encourage that pattern in TypeScript any more, in favor of `if` statements with type guards.

So I guess you could try that. I'm sorry that I can't really help you on the flow side, I can just give general advice on how we recommend modern patterns for TypeScript and hope those reflect in flow.

Generally, you might also look into the official Redux Toolkit, which brings all these abstractions. It is only partially flow-typed, but those types might already cover your needs or you might even improve them.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will definitely change from the switch statement to `ifs` however it should work in both cases and I can confirm that changing to `ifs` did not change anything - still getting `any` instead of a narrowed type :(

Comment: Then take a look at `createSlice` from Redux Toolkit. I think that's typed and that should take care of the whole "writing a reducer thing" anyways :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use switch cases if you build a type generic that has one type string referencing linked with a payload type. I don't know if using cases like the way you have would work, because switch cases are pretty much their own if conditions to test against `string`s in the `case` not `boolean`s.

The below solution leverages type refinement, so based on the conditional JS you've written flow will infer the payload structure. The caveat here is that in your `action` param you have to add all possible type payloads otherwise flow has no idea what structures are available to refine from, this can be broken down somewhere else but also this helps to lock down the variations in your reducer for cases you don't want to handle.

[try-flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBAgmYBUoF4oG8C+AoLpKwGNgBLAewDsEAeBAGigAUA+FdAHyyijwgC4o6nKGACGIADakRAE34NaWNhgDcOHozGSZMVmjZQR-AM7AATsXIBzKEtXqGmqdIBCu-QCNjZi9ds4CFCZQFsQkIuIAysAiwNComKpYAeRBphDSAK4EEKasABRCJjF8sPBIqCFhkdGxClwiRGTk-DCNFNQA5DAAwggAkgDyAHIA+jAd9A4STjAs+q0k7VRdvYOjzhMa0zLOTAoAlC1lKCxohQDuoQQAFlB5DYvkAHQ8++hCXAQiRtAr-cNjDr8M5cUFQNLADKmcjvMFgp4Ioq1D5wwwGNrPUTbaRPER1OEqFHYMFfH5QP5rEYbYEorgQqEwkFwrgIp5IiD45loh5NJ5YrQ4vFQAD0wqgVAAtBLgsAoAAzETEcRGKDuCBfDJk9RpOUWCAq4CkLYC5y00GedGPPmOGRPdyc0GEsHE0HSCAKjLiYC8M306FQdmqLjYFRAA)

```
type AppT = {}

type ActionT<T, P> = {|
  type: T,
  payload: P,
|};

type PayloadA = {| a: string |};
type PayloadB = {| b: string |};

const initialState = {};

const reducer = (
  state: AppT = initialState,
  action: ActionT<'ACTION_A', PayloadA> | ActionT<'ACTION_B', PayloadB>,
): AppT => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ACTION_A': {
      return {
        ...state,
        a: action.payload.a,
      };
    }
    case 'ACTION_B': {
      return {
        ...state,
        a: action.payload.a, // <-- it fails because type refines to PayloadB
        b: action.payload.b,
      };
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: The thing is this solution gets very messy in large code bases in my opinion. In your example it looks ok but we have only 2 payload options. What if we have now a more realistic scenario where there are 8-10 actions? The action parameter in the reducer function would get quite big. Or am I missing something and there is a way to clean it up?

Comment: For TypeScript, we explicitly recommend against distributed union patterns, since they are much more work that type guards and always include a lie to the compiler (no matter how you type it, that reducer will always be called with *all* methods) that actually impacts code flow analysis.
As far as I understand OP explicitly wants to use type guards ( %checks ) in flowtype, so I'm not sure pointing to distributed unions is useful here.